# Selenium WebDriver + java . Locate by class name

Tags: java, selenium, findby

I am trying **Selenium Webdriver** to find input element by class name. I don't have a unique id or name in my input. Programmer added unique class name `" id-input-nazwa"` but i dont know how use this name. 
I tried it:

```
 (By.xpath("//input[@class='component col-xs-12 ng-scope id-input-nazwa col-sm-6 mt-2']"))
```

It is my DOM. I need to find a yellow input and using a yellow class from the `div.  :` 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EumMb.png)

Answer (score 1):

Induce `WebDriverWait` and `visibilityOfElementLocated()` and following locator strategies.

**xpath**:

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//label[text()='Nazwa']/following::input[1]"))).sendKeys("value");
```

**css selector**

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("div.id-input-nazwa input[name*='pbInput']"))).sendKeys("value");
```